# Ubuntu mssql server Corruption detected in persistent registry: \SystemRoot\security.hiv

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

I started having this issue today on our production sql server. I have tried a variety of different fixes proposed online. We are using MSSQL server 2017 (14.0.3257.3-13). I'm out of ideas on what could be causing the server to crash. Below is the recent crash log.

This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Sat Feb  1 14:21:21 2020
The following diagnostic information is available:

```
     Reason: 0x00000007
     Status: 0xc000014c
    Message: Corruption detected in persistent registry: \SystemRoot\security.hiv.
Stack Trace:
             000000006b137250
             000000006b1345bf
             000000006b1347a3
             000000006b1337d3
             000000006b1326f2
             000000006b175c31
    Process: 8815 - sqlservr
     Thread: 8819 (application thread 0x4)
Instance Id: e5a2f812-0426-4d92-b9b2-1db1e60d957c
   Crash Id: 60073e70-4042-4275-9fcd-a05ae84d26f5
Build stamp: 9726a6583fe7826f57b03fd1c7adf12bebe7692cb64630fccb0541c06820af4d
```

Distribution: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
     Processors: 9
   Total Memory: 8589934592 bytes
      Timestamp: Sat Feb  1 14:21:21 2020
     Last errno: 2
Last errno text: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through multiple proposed solutions online nothing worked. Some of the things I tried:

1. Upgrading mssql-server to latest version.
2. Repairing missing files or dependencies.
3. Changing access permissions to the directory.
4. Elevating access permissions for the mssql user.
5. Changing user access to root for the .hiv files located in the mssql .system/system folder

The only way to for me to get it to work was to:

1. Delete all the folders manually from /var/opt/mssql/ except for the
   **data** folder.
2. Re-link python from 3.5 to 2.7
3. Then I downgraded the mssql-server version to Microsoft SQL Server 2017 14.0.3192.2.
4. Run the sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup

   ```
   **Python Re-link**
   sudo rm /user/bin/python
   sudo ln -s /user/bin/python[version] /user/bin/python
   ```

After that everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the ideas, Toret.
I have faced the same issue, but I solved it just by deleting the security.hiv file.

```
rm /var/opt/mssql/.system/system/security.hiv
```

After that the mssql-server service started normaly.